# How to handle multiple levels outlet

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I just modified my app to handle authentication.

Now I have :

one primary outlet (no name) which handle route to access to the app or the login form.

In my app I display a header and a left menu, and a second outlet (named "main") which will display different screens regarding what's selected in the left menu.

In one of those screens I got a third outlet (named "cars") cause I display a div with 4 tabs, so I use this outlet to navigate between those tabs.

So I got no name -> main -> cars.

I'm able to access to the login & app route through the first outlet, I'm also able to navigate on the different screens through the "main" outlet, with url like :

> http://localhost:4200/#/app/(main:screen1)

But I cannot navigate through the third outlet.

First : is that a good way to use outlets or should I use another way?
Is that possible?
And what should the url looks like? For now I try with :

> http://localhost:4200/#/app/(main:accident/(cars:containment))

I must say that before that I add the authentication part (and so the first outlet), this used to work, I use to access this screen with

> http://localhost:4200/#/accident/(cars:containment)